# Visualize the Stacked Lstm

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

Not able to visualize the working of the stacked lstm. Here is the model structure.
[Model Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IN7Bo.png).
Batch size is 16, sequence length is 64, and vocab-size is 86. If anyone represents it in diagram, it would be helpful.

Comment: What do you want to visualize? Structure? Activations? Do you have any example?

Comment: The model structure, How three layers of LSTM be stacked.

Answer (score 0):

You can just search Google images for stacked LSTM. This one is a good minimalistic  example of 2 LSTMs:
[image]